# Extract the second element of a tuple in a pipeline

Tags: tuples, elixir, pipeline

I want to be able to extract the Nth item of a tuple in a pipeline, without using `with` or otherwise breaking up the pipeline. `Enum.at` would work perfectly except for the fact that a tuple is not an enum.

Here's a motivating example:

```
colors = %{red: 1, green: 2, blue: 3}
data = [:red, :red, :blue]
data 
|> Enum.map(&Map.fetch(colors, &1))
|> Enum.unzip
```

This returns `{[:ok, :ok, :ok], [1, 1, 3]}` and let's say I just want to extract `[1, 1, 3]`

(For this specific case I could use `fetch!` but for my actual code that doesn't exist.)

I could add on

```
|> Tuple.to_list
|> Enum.at(1)
```

Is there a better way of doing this that doesn't require creating a temporary list out of each tuple?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use [`Kernel.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2):

```
iex(1)> {[:ok, :ok, :ok], [1, 1, 3]} |> elem(1)
[1, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Ah, I was overthinking things as usual. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Pattern Match** can help

```
{ _status, required_value } = 
  data 
    |> Enum.map(&Map.fetch(colors, &1))
    |> Enum.unzip
```

You can ignore the `_status`.

Comment: I should clarify, the `extract` step is in the middle of the pipeline. Using pattern matching (also my preferred way), ends up requiring intermediate variables and multiple pipes :(